# How is a characteristic subgroup verified?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition

I know the definition of a characteristic subgroup: $\sigma (H)=H$ for all $\sigma \in \text{aut}\, G$ where $H \leq G$. But, I do not understand how $\sigma$ is defined. Surely we can map $H$ to $H' \varsupsetneq H$ in any case?

For example, let us take $G=C_6$ the cyclic group of order 6, and $H=\langle g^2 \rangle = \{1, g^2, g^4\}$ where $g \in G$. Then define the mapping $\sigma : g^k \mapsto g^{k+1}$. Thus, $\sigma(H)=\{g, g^3, g^5\}\neq H$. I chose this particular group because I read on Wikipedia that subgroups of cyclic groups are characteristic.

Comment: Your $\sigma$ is not an automorphism. It does not map the unit to the unit. As you say in the definition you only require that $\sigma(H) = H$ to hold for all automorphisms $\sigma$. Not for all bijections or all functions or all homomorphisms.

Comment: @AlešBizjak isn't an automorphism an isomorphism $G \to G$? IMO $1,g,g^2, ... , g^5$ are all units of $G$.

Comment: Yes, an automorphism is an isomorphism $G \to G$. But, for instance, $g$ is not the unit because, for instance, $g \cdot g = g^2 \neq g$ and the defining property of the unit is that $x \cdot 1 = 1 \cdot x = x$ for any $x$.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the meaning of the word "unit". I use the word "unit" to mean "invertible element" and the word "unity" to mean "identity".

Comment: $\sigma$ has to preserve the group structure:  in particular $ \sigma (1 ) = 1$ - your $\sigma$ does not do that... To be a group automorphism is to be a set automorphism (i.e. invertible map on the set), but also a group homomorphism.

Comment: Thanks, I understand how an automorphism is defined now.

Comment: @AlešBizjak please upgrade your comment to an answer so that I can accept it. (Note: the textbook I used used "unity" to mean 'identity.')

Comment: @ahorn I have done that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $\sigma$ is not an automorphism. It does not map the identity element to the identity element. As you say in the definition you only require that $\sigma(H) = H$ for all *automorphisms* $\sigma$. Not for all bijections or all functions or all homomorphisms.